# Rotate labels for ggplot dendrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, dendextend, ggdendro

I am trying to create a dendrogram using the package dendextend. It creates really nice gg dendrograms but unfortunately when you turn it into a "circle", the labels do not keep up. I'll provide an example below.

My distance object is here: http://speedy.sh/JRVBS/mydist.RDS

```
library(dendextend)
library(ggplot2)
#library(devtools) ; install_github('kassambara/factoextra')
library(factoextra)


clus <- hcut(mydist, k = 6, hc_func = 'hclust', 
             hc_method = 'ward.D2', graph = FALSE, isdiss = TRUE)

dend <- as.dendrogram(clus)
labels(dend) <- paste0(paste0(rep(' ', 3), collapse = ''), labels(dend))
dend <- sort(dend, decreasing = FALSE)

ggd1 <- ggplot(dend %>%
                   set('branches_k_color', k = 6) %>%
                   set('branches_lwd', 0.6) %>%
                   set('labels_colors', k = 6) %>%
                   set('labels_cex', 0.6), 
               theme = theme_minimal(),
               horiz = TRUE)
ggd1 <- ggd1 + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     axis.text = element_blank(),
                     axis.title = element_blank())
ggd1 <- ggd1 + ylim(max(get_branches_heights(dend)), -3)
```

This basically gives me this image: 
[image]
Which is great. However, I want to turn this into a circle, and so use:

```
ggd1 + coord_polar(theta = 'x')
```

And I get this graph below. This is close to exactly what I want, but I just need to rotate the labels.
[image]

Any help is appreciated. I know that under the hood dendextend is basically creating a few data.frames and then calling `geom_segment()` and `geom_text()` on them to create the dendrogram and labels. I believe I can expose the associated data.frame as follows:

```
back.df1 <- dendextend::as.ggdend(dend)
back.df2 <- dendextend::prepare.ggdend(back.df1)
```

Another tactic would possibly to be to use `ggplot(labels = FALSE...)` when plotting, and then to add `geom_text()` manually in some way that preserves the coloring but allows me to use `geom_text(angle = )`.

I also suspect some combination of various ggplot wizardry would allow me to take `back.df2` and create the 1st and second plots again, but also control the angle of the labels. However, I do not know how to do any of this, and have built out a lot already using the dendextend package and would ideally like to avoid having to use any new package for creating dendrogram objects because I really like this outside of the labels!

---

### SOLUTION

I based this off the solution from Richard Telford below. I first created an edited version of the `ggplot.ggdend()`. This is identical to the one provided in the answer below. I next created a function to automatically create the angle and hjust vectors so that the labels rotation switches from 6 o'clock to 12 o'clock to improve readability.

```
createAngleHJustCols <- function(labeldf) {        
    nn <- length(labeldf$y)
    halfn <- floor(nn/2)
    firsthalf <- rev(90 + seq(0,360, length.out = nn))
    secondhalf <- rev(-90 + seq(0,360, length.out = nn))
    angle <- numeric(nn)
    angle[1:halfn] <- firsthalf[1:halfn]
    angle[(halfn+1):nn] <- secondhalf[(halfn+1):nn]

    hjust <- numeric(nn)
    hjust[1:halfn] <- 0
    hjust[(halfn+1):nn] <- 1

    return(list(angle = angle, hjust = hjust))
}
```

I then produced the plot using the following code:

```
gdend <- dendextend::as.ggdend(dend %>%
                                   set('branches_k_color', k = 6) %>%
                                   set('branches_lwd', 0.6) %>%
                                   set('labels_colors', k = 6) %>%
                                   set('labels_cex', 0.6))

gdend$labels$angle <- ifelse(horiz, 0, 90)
gdend$labels$hjust <- 0
gdend$labels$vjust <- 0.5

# if polar, change the angle and hjust so that the labels rotate
if(polarplot) {
    newvalues <- createAngleHJustCols(gdend$labels)
    gdend$labels$angle <- newvalues[['angle']]
    gdend$labels$hjust <- newvalues[['hjust']]
}

ggresult <- newggplot.ggdend(gdend, horiz = TRUE, offset_labels = -2) 
ggresult <- ggresult + ggtitle(plottitle)
ggresult <- ggresult + theme(plot.margin = margin(c(2,2,2,2),
                             axis.text = element_blank(),
                             plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(10,2,2,2)))
ggresult <- ggresult + ylim(max(get_branches_heights(dend)), -5)
ggresult <- ggresult + coord_polar(theta = 'x', direction = 1)
```

And that ultimately produced this final plot!
[image]

(I changed a couple things in the data so some of the order may appear different in the plot)

Comment: Your RDS file seems to be corrupt. `load("mydist.RDS")
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded`. May be better to use `dput` and include in your question (unless object is huge)

Comment: It is unfortunately huge. Thanks for your comment/answer, I'm going to try that. Also, I reuploaded 'mydist.RDS', I believe I may have made a mistake before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but you need to edit `dendextend:::ggplot.ggdend` first to make it accept the `angle` aesthetic (and also `hjust` and `vjust`)

Step 1: edit `dendextend:::ggplot.ggdend`

```
newggplot.ggdend <- function (data, segments = TRUE, labels = TRUE, nodes = TRUE, 
          horiz = FALSE, theme = theme_dendro(), offset_labels = 0, ...) {
  data <- prepare.ggdend(data)
  #angle <- ifelse(horiz, 0, 90)
  #hjust <- ifelse(horiz, 0, 1)
  p <- ggplot()
  if (segments) {
    p <- p + geom_segment(data = data$segments, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", xend = "xend", yend = "yend", colour = "col", linetype = "lty", size = "lwd"), lineend = "square") + 
      guides(linetype = FALSE, col = FALSE) + scale_colour_identity() + 
      scale_size_identity() + scale_linetype_identity()
  }
  if (nodes) {
    p <- p + geom_point(data = data$nodes, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", colour = "col", shape = "pch", size = "cex")) + 
      guides(shape = FALSE, col = FALSE, size = FALSE) + 
      scale_shape_identity()
  }
  if (labels) {
    data$labels$cex <- 5 * data$labels$cex
    data$labels$y <- data$labels$y + offset_labels
    p <- p + geom_text(data = data$labels, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", label = "label", colour = "col", size = "cex", angle = "angle", hjust = "hjust", vjust = "vjust"))#edited
  }
  if (horiz) {
    p <- p + coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0.2, 0))
  }
  if (!is.null(theme)) {
    p <- p + theme
  }
  p
}

assignInNamespace(x = "ggplot.ggdend", ns = "dendextend", value = newggplot.ggdend)
```

Step 2: Make the data object

```
gdend <- dendextend::as.ggdend(dend %>%
                        set('branches_k_color', k = 6) %>%
                        set('branches_lwd', 0.6) %>%
                        set('labels_colors', k = 6) %>%
                        set('labels_cex', 0.6),
                      theme = theme_minimal(),
                      horiz = TRUE)
gdend$labels$angle <- seq(90, -270, length = nrow(gdend$labels))
gdend$labels$vjust <- cos(gdend$labels$angle * pi) / (180)
gdend$labels$hjust <- sin(gdend$labels$angle * pi) / (180)
```

Step 3: plot

```
ggd1 <- ggplot(gdend)
ggd1 <- ggd1 + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     axis.text = element_blank(),
                     axis.title = element_blank())
ggd1 <- ggd1 + ylim(max(get_branches_heights(dend)), -3)
ggd1
ggd1 + coord_polar(theta = 'x')
```

Comment: This looks good, the only thing I needed was to make the labels and the hjust flip over from 6 o'clock to 12 o'clock to improve readability. I'll post an example.

Comment: Hi Richard, any chance you'd be interested in editing the code in dendextend and submit a PR? (I've opened an issue on it here: https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/issues/44) Thanks!